# How to do code review using Lua-Inspect ,ZeroBrane

Tags: lua, zerobrane

I am new to lua language and  I have written a lua code of which i want to do code review using lua-inspect . I am using  ZeroBrane studio as an IDE.

Comment: Have you looked in the zerobrane [documentation](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-lua-debugging) ?

Answer (score 2):

lua-inspect is already integrated into ZeroBrane Studio. You can run it on a current file using `Project | Analyze`. See the documentation for other related [static analyzer options](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-general-preferences#static-analyzer).